# Visual Studio 2017 Deployment Error on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: visual-studio-2017, windows-10-iot-core

I've been developing my Windows Store App for over a month, and all of a sudden I get this error when I try to run it in Visual Studio 2017 on my developer machine:
[Visual Studio Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5GPD.png)

(DEP0600 Deployment Failed. Failed to deploy through new deployment pipeline)

(DEP8000 Unexpected deployment failure: AggregateException : One or more errors occurred)

This error only occurs at my current project, not at a standard template for example.

I already cleaned and rebuild my solution but still no success.

At the moment I run 
Target Version : Windows 10 Anniversary Edition(10.0; Build 14393)
and 
Min Version : Windows 10(10.0; Build 10586).

Comment: Which version was the windows 10 IoT that you wanted to deploy the app to?

Comment: v.10.0.16299.64 is currently installed.

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was that my app was already running. I set it as the startup app and after that I couldn't redeploy the newer version. Stopping the app solved the problem.

Comment: that was my problem too.  It was running as the startup app

Answer (score 1):

DEP8000 just means that an agregated thread encountered an error and is thrown to the parent thread.

The real issue here is DEP0600.

I encountered [a solution on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c7c8b1a-f6e9-40a8-b254-cbd907e07eb3/dep0600-failed-to-deploy-through-ne-deployment-pipeline-surface-hub?forum=wpdevelop).

Basicaly it can occur if any of your filenames has accented characters (á, ô. õ, é) ect.

Rename all your files to remove these and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the ***Universal Window Target Version*** as Windows 10 Fall Creators Update(10.0;Build 16299).
[image]

If you can not find this version option,you need to install the WDK for 16299, this is the download [link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit).Please try it,and feel free to let me know if there is any problem.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't worked so far. It is still the same error like before. With the newer Target Version I also can't run it. It seems like my windows version is too old. (Current Windows 10 on my working maschine : 14393)

Comment: Please try to update your Windows 10 PC to 16299,and then deploy again.On another hand,have you cleaned and rebuilt your solution? Please try.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problems when working with Deploying UWP app to HoloLens.

Here are few steps that can help:

1. Clean & Rebuild solution
2. Deleting .vs folder can help
3. Else you can just rename the package name under project settings.